# I have a question while creating a Singly Linked List

Tags: javascript, linked-list, nodes

I got curious while making shift method.
Please look at the code first.

```
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    push(val) {
        let newNode = new Node(val);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = this.head;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        }
        this.length++;
        return this;
    }
    shift() {
        if (!this.head) return undefined;
        let first = this.head
        this.head = first.next
        this.length--;

        return this
    }
}

let list = new SinglyLinkedList()
list.push("1")
list.push("2")
list.shift()
```

The result of the above code is as follows.

```
{
    "head": {
        "val": "2",
        "next": null
    },
    "tail": {
        "val": "2",
        "next": null
    },
    "length": 1
}
```

I called shift() one more time, and the results are as follows.

```
{
    "head": null,
    "tail": {
        "val": "2",
        "next": null
    },
    "length": 0
}
```

I thought the value of the "tail" would be null, but it wasn't.
Maybe it's because I don't have enough knowledge about Node, but I don't know exactly what I'm missing.
Can you tell me why these results are produced?

When I added an if statement, I got the result I wanted.

```
    shift() {
        if (!this.head) return undefined;
        let first = this.head
        this.head = first.next
        this.length--;
        // add
        if (this.length === 0) {
            this.tail = null;
        }
        return this
    }
```

```
{
    "head": null,
    "tail": null,
    "length": 0
}
```

Comment: Well your original `.shift()` code makes no changes to `.tail`, so your fix seems correct to me.

Comment: It's not clear what your confusion is. `tail` won't change by itself.

Comment: Oh, I did something stupid, mistaking "next" for automatically connecting to "tail".
This is just a code I make from scratch!

Comment: Unrelated, why did you assign to `first`?